# Flash racing game physics

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, physics, racing

I want to make AS3 top-down racing game. I wrote core code, but now I want to make game more realistic. I need some physics (acceleration, steering, drifting and etc.). Problem is that I suck in physics and math. I need some materials for that stuff if available. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a physics engine, or just information about physics? If it's the latter, you might want to check out [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yah you can also check out this http://www.box2dflash.org/ Though you may end up really just wanting to learn about the physics involved for your game it's really not generally too complicated you just have to think about everything in terms of force.  If you program using F=ma and choose reasonable/realistic values your math will work out well.  Friction forces are easy enough to find http://regentsprep.org/regents/physics/phys01/friction/default.htm the only hard part I see with a car game is determining the change in friction for each tire based on the acceleration change from turning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physics engines are around for people like you and myself who 'suck at math'.

As mentioned in comments, [Box2D](http://www.box2dflash.org/) is probably the most well-known and easiest to find tutorials for getting started.

Get started at:

- [Introduction to Box2D for Flash andAS3](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/introduction-to-box2d-for-flash-and-as3/)
- [Todd's Box2D Tutorials!](http://www.kerp.net/box2d/)